# WinAPI. Перерисовка изображения при изменении окна

Tags: winapi

Есть класс, который принимает в конструктор HWND окна, и строку с адресом файла. Все это выводится. Но как только изменяется размер окна, изображение исчезает. Класс выглядит так (начинаю с конструктора):

```
HWND hWND;
HPEN hPen;
RECT r;
COLORREF colorref;
HDC hDC, CompatibleDC;
BITMAP Bitmap;
int widht, heigth;
LPCWSTR path;
HANDLE HndBitmap;

public: ImageOutClass(HWND arg, LPCWSTR arg_): hWND(arg), path(arg_){ 
    if (FILE_OPEN) {
        hDC = GetDC(hWND);
        CompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        SelectObject(CompatibleDC, hPen);
        HndBitmap = LoadImage(NULL, path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 905, 677, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        GetObject(HndBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &Bitmap);
        SelectObject(CompatibleDC, HndBitmap);
        StretchBlt(hDC, (DISPLAY_WDTH - widht) / 2, (DISPLAY_HEIGHT - heigth) / 2, widht, heigth, CompatibleDC, 0, 0, widht, heigth, SRCCOPY);
        //setColorArray(widht, heigth);
    }
}

void run() {
    if (FILE_OPEN) {
        hDC = GetDC(hWND);
        CompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        SelectObject(CompatibleDC, hPen);
        HndBitmap = LoadImage(NULL, path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 905, 677, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        GetObject(HndBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &Bitmap);
        SelectObject(CompatibleDC, HndBitmap);
        widht = Bitmap.bmWidth;
        heigth = Bitmap.bmHeight;
        ratio();
        StretchBlt(hDC, (DISPLAY_WDTH - widht) / 2, (DISPLAY_HEIGHT - heigth) / 2, widht, heigth, CompatibleDC, 0, 0, widht, heigth, SRCCOPY);      
    }
}
```

Метод `run()`, вызывается в при событии "`case WM_PAINT: imageout.run();` "

Неужели для перерисовки изображения нужно заново открывать файл и делать всю ту процедуру загрузки? Если просто все инициализировать, а вызывать только StretchBlt(hDC,...), то почему то ничего не происходит и изображения не выводятся, нужно опять проходить полный путь. Как это все правильно организовать чтоб не читать постоянно файл изображения, а из какого нибудь буфера?

Answer (score 1):

Рисовать в окне нужно только в обработчике `WM_PAINT`. Для рисования нужно использовать функции `BeginPaint()` и `EndPaint()`. В вашем коде полно утечек памяти (GDI-хэндлов). Если вы вызываете `GetDC()` не забывайте вызывать в конце `ReleaseDC()`. Вы также игнорируете возвращаемое значение функции `SelectObject()`. 
Если говорить про ваш вопрос, то что вам мешает загрузить картинку (`HBITMAP`) один раз и сохранить ее в поле класса?

Comment: HBITMAP в моем случае не используется. Данные файла загрузки - HANDLE HndBitmap. Я использую код с примера. Конечно HANDLE это поле класса, и если я его инициализирую в конструкторе, то он только в конструкторе и работает, а в методе run(), HndBitmap как буд то пустой , или наполнен непонятно чем, и изображения нет. Об всяких утечках, я пока не парюсь, главное вывести изображение нормально, а потом буду заниматься остальными вопросами.

Comment: @ПетрЮрьевич Покажите минимальный компилируемый код, чтобы я помог вам его исправить

Comment: Решил проблему, нужно было создать обьект и присвоить ему значение : HGDIOBj = SelectObject(CompatibleDC, HndBitmap); а не просто вызывать функцию. Хотя переменная не используется (кроме как в операторе if на существование), но возможно операционная система это учитиывает и сохраняет остальные значения, которые больше не нужно переинициализировать.